# create dataframes using the loop parameter as part of the dataframe name

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I will loop through 12 months.

How do I write these two lines in such a way that the loop parameter takes the values from 1 to 12 when substituting the value of “1” in these lines:

```py
df_month_1[‘a’] = df_month_1[‘Jan’]
code_month[1] = len(df_month_1)
```

so the result is:

```py
df_month_1[‘a’] = df_month_1[‘x’]
code_month[1] = len(df_month_1)
… 
df_month_12[‘a’] = df_month_12[‘x’]
code_month[12] = len(df_month_12)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the `df_month_i` into a list then iterate over the list. Rather than adding them explicitly, you can use [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function which returns a dictionary with all the defined variables to simplify this process.

```py
for i in range(12):
    month = f'df_month_{i+1}'
    df_months.append(globals()[month])

for i, df_month in enumerate(df_months):
    df_month['a'] = df_month['x']
    code_month[i+1] = len(df_month)
```